# How do I implement with local file on hard drive?

Tags: python, api, python-requests

How do I implement with local file on hard drive? I want it to access MP3's from my local hard drive instead of using the internet.

```
import requests


data = {

    'url': 'http://www.bensound.org/bensound-music/bensound-dubstep.mp3',
    'return': 'timecode,apple_music,deezer,spotify',
    'api_token': 'test'
     }

 result = requests.post('https://api.audd.io/', data=data)

print(result.text)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this -

```
import requests
import os


file_name = os.path.basename(file_path)

data = {

'file': (file_name, open(file_path, 'rb')),
'return': 'timecode,apple_music,deezer,spotify',
'api_token': 'test'
 }

result = requests.post('https://api.audd.io/', data=data)

print(result.text)
```